# Prepend vue options in select field with "please choose...." option

Tags: javascript, sql-server, vuejs2

I am trying to add an option into a select field that is populated from a database query. How can I add a "Please Choose..." option that is disabled?

Here is the select code:

```
              <b-select v-model="project" class="form-control">
              <option :key="project.ProjectID" v-for="project in projects" :value="project"> {{ project.ProjectName }}</option>
               </b-select>
```

and here is my method:

```
              loadProjects() {
                    axios
                      .get('/api/project')
                      .then((res) => {
                        console.log(res.data)
                        this.projects = res.data
                        this.project = res.data[0]
                      })
                      .catch(err => console.log('errors:' + err))
                  },
```

I have searched everywhere for something to guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Add one `<option>` element with `attr=disabled` into the slot of `<b-select>` like below:

```
<b-select v-model="project" class="form-control">
  <option value="Please choose..." disabled>Please choose...</option>
  <option :key="project.ProjectID" v-for="project in projects" :value="project"> {{project.ProjectName }}</option>
</b-select>
```

Comment: By adding the **disabled** option, you prevent "please choose" from ever being selected, and it will default to auto-selecting the first item from the array, essentially rendering that whole addition pointless. Drop the **disabled** and it will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Make the first element of the project array "Please Choose ...". Then push the incoming data to the project directory. After that "Please Choose ..." will appear at first. "Please Choose ...". Finally, check the "value" property with a script. Continue without evaluating the "Please Select ..." value. The simplest method looks like this. If something different comes to mind later, I will help you.